# How Do I Shift Field of Study?

Tags: career-path, early-career, code

I am medical student at Alexandria University, Egypt and I have a question important to my life. I have no passion in what I have learned. I love medicine but not by that way we have to study it. How can I deal with that? I love programming but I am not professional in it. I am thinking about career shift as I feel my life has been stolen from me, unfortunately I am 23 years old and I don't know what I can do!

Comment: Please try to improve your question title. As. The current title could be used for a wide variety of questions on this site.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? You have studied med school, but don't enjoy it and you're looking to switch fields?

Comment: Questions like this are usually best discussed with people who know you well.  It's hard for total strangers to give you useful career advice.

Comment: @J.Roibal yes!  With existential mental problems

Comment: @NateEldredge you are completely right but sometimes stranger can give you better objective answer

Comment: I made a few edits to your question and I will now answer it.

Comment: If you have the means to support yourself, don't let age dissuade you. I started my undergrad at 25; the oldest 1st year Ph.D. student we later had was 42. Just make sure that the new field really appeals to you - along the lines of @J.Roibal's answer, grab an introductory text book from that field, learn and apply a programming language, etc. An alternative is to finish your degree, then do a Masters or so in a field combining the two - bioinformatics, neuroscience, or such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello User41022 and Welcome to Stack Exchange. First off I would like to start my answer by saying that many people have experienced what you are going through at your age, including myself. 23 is an age where you have enough life experience that you know what you like and what you don't like. I am 29 years old, so I have a bit of perspective and experience on what you are going through. Here is my advice to you:

If you have spent a number of years in a field and decided that it is not "for you", either because you are not passionate about it or you are not good at it, and you have a passion in another field, I would STRONGLY recommend that you follow your passion into the other field. Now, that advice does not mean immediately tell your supervisor "I quit!" and then jump into the next field, it means, slowly begin to transition (by spending time learning) the new field so that you have the opportunity to follow your passion. If you are in medical school, you are clearly an intelligent person who has skills and connections. Your task is to now use the skills, experience and network you have developed over the past few years to transition to the field you are interested in.

You mentioned that you are interested in computer programming. I recommend taking a few online courses in Python (or another computer programming language) and begin applying these computer programming concepts to your current field in medical research. You simply do not want to throw away years of education and experience for a brand new industry, nor do you want to burn bridges with your network. By slowly transitioning from where you are to where you want to be, you will be much better off now and in the future.